# Triggering an onChange that requires event via programmatically changed input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is best explained with a code example:

```
    <input type="text" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setA} /> // inputA
    <input type="text" value={this.state.b} onChange={this.setB} /> // inputB

    setA(e) {
      this.setState({a: e.target.value});
    }

    setB(e) {
      this.setState({b: e.target.value});
      // at this point, the inputA.value changes due to state change
      setA(???) // update the state with inputA's new value
    }
```

I want to set `this.state.a` to the new value held within `inputA`, however I have to call the `setA()`  method manually because the input value changes programmatically. The problem with this, is I require the `inputA` even passed in so that I can get the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question above shows `controlled` inputs in use. Everything in render depends on `state` or `props`. There is no definite way to update the state. As in this case, you are relying on the `change` event to update the `state A`, while your logic suggests that `state a` also depends on `state b`. So your `setB` function should be something like below

```
 setB(e) {
  const b = e.target.value;
  let a = this.state.a; // gives your the current value of a, which is also present in the state

  // do calculations to determine your new A
  // Then set your state like below

   this.setState({b, a }); // Both your inputs would reflect the new values in the state
}
```

Even if you don't set the value of `a` in `setB`, `input a` would retain its old value.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you not pass value to the input

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setA} />
<input type="text" value={this.state.b} onChange={this.setB} />
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of updating `this.state.a` in the first place when `inputB` value changes. I have edited the post with further clarity.

Comment: I updated the original post to reflect closer to my actual case.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your onChange method with onChange={ () => {this.setB}}. It will work..

Comment: How does this help to set the value of `a` to `inputA.value` after `setB()` is called? For reference, I have omitted the code that binds `this` to the methods.

Comment: You need to change second function declaration as well onChange={ () => {this.setA}}